# GRAILS holds js files

Tags: javascript, grails

There is a Grails project with heavy JavaScript development. The problem is that when Grails server is running, JS files which are being edited, occasionally cannot be saved. The editor (e.g. Sublime) refuses to save them because they are read-only. For the first it is possible to save JS files, but for the second and further it is not possible to do it, unless a lot of time has passed. Obviously, Grails recompiles resources, but it seems like it 'forgots' to unlock JS-files and I must restart Grails which is stupid and wastes really a lot of time.

Can this problem be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: I had problems with this too. It's interesting that if you use Eclipse this error not happens. I suggest you to open a [JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/) with the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've never had this happen in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing and using another editor.